# Can we eat the food which comes from a religious celebration or festival

Tags: sharia, food

Can we eat the food which is kept in front of idols. In my company after celebrating the festivals (some fruits or coconut in front of idols)they give it to all the employees Is it halal?.

In the ayah [Surat Baqarah:173](http://quran.com/2/173) (emphasis mine):

> He has only forbidden to you dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine, and ***that which has been dedicated to other than Allah.*** But whoever is forced [by necessity], neither desiring [it] nor transgressing [its limit], there is no sin upon him. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

Mention that it is haram. But
sometimes I thought that after reciting bismillah Can we it that?(note that I am talking about only fruits not meat)

Answer (score -1):

THE ANSWER WILL BE "NO"
IT IS AS SAME AS YOU SAY
"CAN I HAVE INTOXICANTS AFTER SAYING BISMILLAH" 
 see how Allah (SWT) make one's every doubt conspicuous: as in the said verse had Almighty befallen only the verse up to ''other than Allah" then your question was valid but as Almighty is all aware , Almighty knows there will be some necessity too so in necessary we can have them!
now, my question to you is 
"what is the necessity of having those things"?
indeed no necessity is there; 
"HENCE YOUR THEORY IS REJECTED" 
but as "DEEDS ARE AS PER THE INTENTIONS" SO IF A MUSLIM gives it as charity, and his intention is to please ALLAH(SWT) AND ASSOCIATE NONE OTHER IN THIS THEN THIS FOOD IS HALAL . ONE COULD give or distribute food or anything else BY THENAME OF THE VERY PERSON BUT FOR THE NAME OF ALLAH(SWT).. 
MOREOVER the food from ANY nonbeliever festival is HARAM!
and what Allah knows we know not'' 
hope you understand!!

Comment: Thanks, But the thing is I already told that I am not asking about the haram food like meet and Intoxicants I am talking about halal food. Second I am not putting any theory to prove that it is halal and I wouldn’t eat also. And **dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine, and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah.** the animals which are slaughtered in non islamic way is totally haram and can't be reversed but The fruits, and sweat are not like that. there is a difference they can be reversed.

Comment: I am not trying to prove If you have any reference from fiqh or from any authentic book please give.thanks,

Comment: you don't get me properly !! 
The Sweets and fruits you are talking about are haram as they are being dedicated to one other than Allah (SWT). that's why I quoted an example of intoxication which is haram in its own by saying Bismillah it won't turn halal. similarly fruits and sweets if from religious festivals are dedicated to one other than Allah (SWT)  it is haram. You can check surah al-Maida verse: 03 further . In this verse Allah (SWT) CLEARLY ORDERS ONE NOT TO EAT THOSE FOOD THAT ARE ATTRIBUTED TO STONES AND IT IS FOOD REGARDLESS OF MEAT AND ALL THAT!

Comment: I asked this Question on a islamic forum they replied that After reciting only fruits or sweat not the meat you may eat that but I am not satisfied with that answer also. because they have not explain deeply just replied "
Yes, you can eat and if it contains meat, you should make sure that the meat is halal."